# Show last text on Textbox

Tags: vb.net

Well, I've done a pretty messed up coding to do in VB [2013]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  If TextBox1.Text <= 10 Then
      TextBox1.Text += 2
  ElseIf TextBox1.Text > 10 Then
      TextBox1.Text = "Greater than 10!"
      Button1.Enabled = False
  End If

End Sub
```

Now all I need is to display the last message that have been on the Textbox. For example:

"Greater than 10!"

"Your last message is: 11"

Comment: You are interchanging Strings and numbers. Switch Option Strict On to find all the places where a possible issue could occur.

Comment: Can you teach me how? Sorry i'm a newbie here on Visual Basic =(

Comment: Well, I haved managed to turn on the Option Strict to On, but now what would I do? =( Please teach me sensei

Comment: I have the Strict, Explicit, Infer to turned on now, but what should I do next?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display "Your last message is: 11" when "Greater than 10!" message will display, then you have to change your else statement

```
TextBox1.Text = "Greater than 10!"
```

by

```
TextBox1.Text = "Greater than 10!" & " Your last message is:" & TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: I've tried this is this is the pretty and only code that works for me :) Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 2):

This won't  fix your issue but it's strongly recommended anyway. Use `Option Strict` always, then `TextBox1.Text <= 10` won't compile anymore because you can't compare a string with an integer. It's helpful to prevent unwanted implicit conversions or other issues. It also helps to understand .NET types. Therefore go to *"Tools/Options/Projects&Solutions"* and set following to `On`: `Strict`(!), `Explicit`, `Infer`.

According  to the actual issue. If you want to have an `Integer` from a `String` use `System.Int32.Parse` or (if the format can be invalid as with user input) `Int32.TryParse`:

```
Dim number As Int32
If Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, number) Then
    If number <= 10 Then 
        number += 2
        TextBox1.Text = number.ToString()
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Greater than 10!"
        Button1.Enabled = False 
    End If
Else
    TextBox1.Text = "Not an integer!"
    Button1.Enabled = False 
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort sir, but this isn't the code I'm looking for =( [and you have a pretty neat code there]